# Best way to dynamically display several images as a list or table in Qt?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

I would like to dynamically add and display images in a list or a table, probably with a scroll bar in Qt. However, I do not know what is the best choice to do so.

Comment: Are you looking for a PyQt or c++ solution? You've tagged the question with both, but it should really only be tagged with what you are looking for.

Comment: Python solution but as both languages can use Qt, I thought the solution will remain the same whatever the language.

Comment: It's quite a typical use case for QListView/QListWidget

Comment: QListWidget is what I was looking for and seems to better fit my needs than QTableWidget one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Qt provides an example called `FlowLayout`. Newly added widgets get automatically arranged in grid-like manner. When the window gets resized, the arrangement of the grid is updated to accommodate the new layout dimensions.

In Qt, it serves as an example how to implement your own layout class derived from QLayout. Find useful documentation here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html

Copy-paste the class and use it for example like this:

```
FlowLayout *flowLayout = new FlowLayout(this);
flowLayout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize);
for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    flowLayout->addWidget(new MyWidget(i));
```